# what is the best practices for sandbox database

Tags: mysql, laravel, testing, environment, sandbox

We are currently working for a booking website and there are many partners that can integrate with our website via REST APIs. We need to give our partner a test environment during the integration process and we have three suggestions

1. Create the testing booking and production booking on the same database and the same table with different number formats. ( like add T letter before the booking number)
2. Create a different table for the testing booking.
3. Both testing and production bookings in the same table and the same format but with a flag to distinguish the testing booking.
   Please advise us with the most correct solution or if there is another solution.

Comment: Entirely separate servers and databases, with test-specific non-PII sample data, ideally.

Comment: I agree with @ceejayoz. I would create a different endpoint for test API, also having tests on production will make things harder and your data integrity rate will go down when creating reports or processing data. To be honest I wouldn't want to work for that company :D.

Comment: +1 at my place we have a dedicated partner sandbox environment with their own subdomain using 123reg/loadbalancers